# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.3.0.0, Cultur

Tags: c#, json

```
string jsonDoc = @"{
    ""pricingDetails"": [{
            ""pricingStrategyId"": 1,
            ""pricingStrategy"": {
                ""id"": 1,
                ""name"": ""PREPAY_FIXED"",
                ""displayText"": ""Prepay fixed"",
                ""description"": ""Pay onsite a fixed price at entry.""
            },
            ""siteId"": 262,
            ""site"": {
                ""id"": 262,
                ""buildingId"": 64,
                ""siteName"": ""Test Site"",
                ""siteDescription"": ""test1"",
                ""isListed"": null,
                ""listedDateTime"": null,
                ""siteAfterHoursInstructions"": null,
                ""archiveDateTime"": null,
                ""archivedBy"": null,
                ""createdDateTime"": ""2019-04-09T00:00:00"",
                ""modifyDateTime"": ""2019-04-09T14:59:54.87"",
                ""statusId"": 5,
                ""siteMaxHeight"": ""2.1"",
                ""businessRegistrationId"": ""2019-105A110BU69L64B262"",
                ""businessAbnOracnNumber"": ""48 110 366 946"",
                ""businessPhoneNumber"": ""02 9017 1292"",
                ""businessFaxNumber"": """",
                ""bankAccountName"": null,
                ""bankAccountNumber"": null,
                ""bankBsbnumber"": null,
                ""bankEmailAddresses"": null,
                ""physicalAddressLine2"": """",
                ""physicalAddressSuburb"": ""Sydney"",
                ""physicalAddressState"": ""NSW"",
                ""physicalAddressPostcode"": 2000,
                ""postalAddressLine2"": """",
                ""postalAddressSuburb"": ""Sydney"",
                ""postalAddressState"": ""NSW"",
                ""postalAddressPostcode"": 2000,
                ""entryAddressLine2"": null,
                ""exitAddressLine2"": null,
                ""bankReferenceNo"": null,
                ""isGstregistered"": null,
                ""refParentBankDets"": false,
                ""canTakePayments"": false,
                ""siteOpenTime"": 60,
                ""siteCloseTime"": 1260,
                ""siteAccessOpenTime"": 360,
                ""siteAccessCloseTime"": 1080,
                ""occupiedTypeId"": 2,
                ""siteNotes"": null,
                ""securityType"": true,
                ""keyDelivery"": 3,
                ""keyInstrPickup"": null,
                ""keyInstrReturn"": null,
                ""smartCmsgLine1"": null,
                ""smartCmsgLine2"": null,
                ""instrGracePeriod"": null,
                ""instrOverstay"": null,
                ""isUnusedBay"": false,
                ""navStatusId"": 0,
                ""navErrorMsg"": null,
                ""priorityPass"": null,
                ""siteCommision"": 0,
                ""entryGracePeriod"": null,
                ""exitGracePeriod"": null,
                ""bookableDays"": null,
                ""checkQuota"": null,
                ""totalSpaces"": null
            },
            ""days"": 31,
            ""entryTimeOffset"": 360,
            ""exitTimeOffset"": 1080,
            ""price"": 7.00
        }
    ],
    ""relatedDevices"": [{
            ""id"": 15,
            ""siteId"": 262,
            ""roleId"": 2,
            ""role"": {
                ""id"": 2,
                ""name"": ""SC"",
                ""description"": ""Display device""
            },
            ""sideId"": 1,
            ""side"": {
                ""id"": 1,
                ""name"": ""IN""
            },
            ""lane"": 1,
            ""deviceGroup"": ""Live""
        }, {
            ""id"": 17,
            ""siteId"": 262,
            ""uid"": ""synorb1-exit1-ptg"",
            ""roleId"": 4,
            ""role"": {
                ""id"": 4,
                ""name"": ""PTG"",
                ""description"": ""Payment device""
            },
            ""sideId"": 1,
            ""side"": {
                ""id"": 1,
                ""name"": ""IN""
            },
            ""lane"": 1,
            ""deviceGroup"": ""Live""
        }
    ]
}
"
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParkingOfferDetailsDTO>(jsonDoc);

==================================

public class ParkingOfferDetailsDTO
    {
        public List<CasualParkingPricingDetailsVM> PricingDetails { get; set; }

        public List<AccessDeviceVM> RelatedDevices { get; set; }
    }

    public class CasualParkingPricingDetailsVM
    {
        public int PricingStrategyId { get; set; }
        public virtual CasualParkingPricingStrategyVM PricingStrategy { get; set; }
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public virtual SitesVM Site { get; set; }
        // Enum.Days | 
        public int Days { get; set; }
        public int? EntryTimeOffset { get; set; }
        public int? ExitTimeOffset { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class CasualParkingPricingStrategyVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class SitesVM
    {
        public SitesVM()
        {
            //Bookings = new HashSet<Bookings>();
            //InventoryEntityRelationship = new HashSet<InventoryEntityRelationship>();
            //ParkingTypes = new HashSet<ParkingTypes>();
            //SiteLicenses = new HashSet<SiteLicenses>();
            //SiteTimeZones = new HashSet<SiteTimeZonesVM>();
            //Spaces = new HashSet<Spaces>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        //public string Photos { get; set; }
        //public bool? HasOnSiteStaff { get; set; }
        //public string OnSiteStaffNotes { get; set; }
        public string SiteDescription { get; set; }
        public bool? IsListed { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ListedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string SiteAfterHoursInstructions { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ArchiveDateTime { get; set; }
        public string ArchivedBy { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifyDateTime { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public string SiteMaxHeight { get; set; }
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        public string BusinessRegistrationId { get; set; }
        public string BusinessAbnOracnNumber { get; set; }
        public string BusinessPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string BusinessEmail { get; set; }
        public string BusinessFaxNumber { get; set; }
        public string BankAccountName { get; set; }
        public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string BankBsbnumber { get; set; }
        public string BankEmailAddresses { get; set; }
        public string PhysicalAddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string PhysicalAddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string PhysicalAddressSuburb { get; set; }
        public string PhysicalAddressState { get; set; }
        public int PhysicalAddressPostcode { get; set; }
        public string PostalAddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string PostalAddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string PostalAddressSuburb { get; set; }
        public string PostalAddressState { get; set; }
        public int? PostalAddressPostcode { get; set; }
        public string EntryAddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string ExitAddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string BankReferenceNo { get; set; }
        public bool? IsGstregistered { get; set; }
        public bool RefParentBankDets { get; set; }
        public bool CanTakePayments { get; set; }
        public short? SiteOpenTime { get; set; }
        public short? SiteCloseTime { get; set; }
        public short? SiteAccessOpenTime { get; set; }
        public short? SiteAccessCloseTime { get; set; }
        public int OccupiedTypeId { get; set; }
        public string SiteNotes { get; set; }
        public bool SecurityType { get; set; }
        public int? KeyDelivery { get; set; }
        public string KeyInstrPickup { get; set; }
        public string KeyInstrReturn { get; set; }
        public string SmartCmsgLine1 { get; set; }
        public string SmartCmsgLine2 { get; set; }
        public string InstrGracePeriod { get; set; }
        public string InstrOverstay { get; set; }
        public bool IsUnusedBay { get; set; }
        public byte NavStatusId { get; set; }
        public string NavErrorMsg { get; set; }
        public string EntryAddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string EntryAddressSuburb { get; set; }
        public string EntryAddressState { get; set; }
        public int? EntryAddressPostcode { get; set; }
        public string ExitAddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string ExitAddressSuburb { get; set; }
        public string ExitAddressState { get; set; }
        public int? ExitAddressPostcode { get; set; }
        public bool? IsPublicSearchable { get; set; }
        public string PriorityPass { get; set; }
        public float SiteCommision { get; set; }
        public short? EntryGracePeriod { get; set; }
        public short? ExitGracePeriod { get; set; }
        public int? BookableDays { get; set; }
        public bool? CheckQuota { get; set; }
        public int? TotalSpaces { get; set; }

        //public virtual Buildings Building { get; set; }
        //public virtual RefNavStatus NavStatus { get; set; }
        //public virtual RefStatus Status { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Bookings> Bookings { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<InventoryEntityRelationship> InventoryEntityRelationship { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<ParkingTypes> ParkingTypes { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<SiteLicenses> SiteLicenses { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<SiteTimeZonesVM> SiteTimeZones { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Spaces> Spaces { get; set; }
    }

public class AccessDeviceVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public AccessDeviceRoleVM Role { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int SideId { get; set; }
        public AccessDeviceSideVM Side { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Lane { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DeviceGroup { get; set; }
    }

 public class AccessDeviceRoleVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccessDeviceSideVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

================
I am tring to deserialize a JSON string in to a nested object. However, it results in an exception. To me the exception looks irrelevant.

Above I have shared the JSON and the C# Class structure. I am trying to Deserialize the JSON but it
throws  "Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, exception...."

I have also tried using a simple object structure and JSON, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

So, as mentioned before, the exception is irrelevant (not helpful). Here is how I debug this issue.

1) Add ErrorHandler

```
// Created a JsonSerializerSettings and passed it to DeserializeObject

var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Error = ErrorHandler };
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParkingOfferDetailsDTO>(responseJson, jsonSettings);

/// Actual handler method
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        private void ErrorHandler(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            errors.Add(e.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
```

This helped in two ways, 
1) There is no exception thrown but the same error (exception) is passed to the error handler.
2) The (incomplete) serialized object is returned. 
This pointed out which part of object serialization is causing an exception.

Now issue in my code/model. I have [Required] attribute on some properties. Not sure why but that caused the Deserialization error.